# Scheme: Recursion with list append

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have a recursive function that basically keeps appending elements to a list recursively until a condition has been met.  There's an issue though, and that's to use `append`, we must give it a quoted list.  So doing

```
 (append (1 2) 3)
```

gives us an error.

The problem is when I first pass a list to the argument, I can put the `'` to make it a quoted list.  However, once I append something to that list and it gets recursively passed to the same function again, the second time `append` tries to work, it will see the list is no longer quoted, so Scheme thinks it's a procedure rather than a list.  Let me show you a simplified version of the code:

```
 (define simple
   (lambda (x y)
      (if (equal? x '()) 
          (display 'success!)
          (simple (cdr x) (append y (car x))))))
```

We run the function by doing `(simple '(1 2 3) '())`
I realize the program above is useless; it's just to demonstrate what I'm saying.

Thanks!

Comment: apply `quote` to the argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with the code you posted isn't that Scheme is confusing a procedure with a list; the trouble is with the call to `append`.

It can be helpful to trace the execution of a procedure when debugging.  Here's what's shown when I run your code with tracing turned on for `simple` and `append`, using `trace-define` in Petite Chez Scheme:

```
> (simple '(1 2 3) '())
|(simple (1 2 3) ())
| (append () 1)
| 1
|(simple (2 3) 1)
| (append 1 2)
```

Because `(append () 1)` returns `1`, in the first recursive call to `simple`, the second argument is `1` rather than a list.  So, you get an error on the next call to `append`.

You could fix it by wrapping your `(car x)` call in a call to `list`:

```
(define simple
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (equal? x '()) 
        (display 'success!)
        (simple (cdr x) (append y (list (car x)))))))
```

Here's a trace of the fixed version running:

```
> (simple '(1 2 3) '())
|(simple (1 2 3) ())
| (append () (1))
| (1)
|(simple (2 3) (1))
| (append (1) (2))
| (1 2)
|(simple (3) (1 2))
| (append (1 2) (3))
| (1 2 3)
|(simple () (1 2 3))
success!|#<void>
```

Answer (score 0):

To append an element to the end of a list, put the element inside a list (`append` is defined *only* between lists). For example, in your code do this:

```
(append y (list (car x)))
```

Of course, that doesn't change the fact that the procedure is doing nothing as it is. At least, return the value accumulated in `y`:

```
(define simple
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (equal? x '())
        y
        (simple (cdr x)
                (append y (list (car x)))))))
```